# Use of TypeName<protocol_name> in variable declaration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, protocols

Usually when it comes to declare a variable as a protocol it's done as follows:

```
id<protocol_name> variable;
```

But recently I've seen something that I don't fully understand. The compiler allows you to define things like:

```
NSString<protocol_name> *variable;
```

In fact assigning from other "plain" NSString variable will cause the compiler to warn you and you'll need to cast it.

I've seen it in JSONModel and the framework uses it to "annotate" properties.

But, apart from that what is it intended for? What are the benefits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benefits is with `variable` you can work as with `NSString*` and `id<protocol_name>`.
You may need all interfaces and don't need type casting.

"plain" NSString is not conform to protocol "protocol_name" and compiler doesn't allows that.

But you can make NSString conform protocol with categories:

```
@interface NSString(protocol_name) < protocol_name >
@end
```

Actually `NSString<protocol_name>` is bad example, because you can't subclass `NSString`.

With other classes that you can subclass, you can implement that protocol in childs.

Comment: At first it could be seen as you can act on "variable" as being an NSString as well as a "protocol_name", but as you have stated you can make it conform to the protocol using Categories... And xCode will assist you and the compiler won't complain. That was another thing that made doubt about the utility of using that variable declaration. Apart from the use case of JSONModel (metadata) I can't still figure out a real value for this.

Comment: I've been thinking about it and maybe I'd have found a useful use case for that.  Sometimes I need to declare some "package protected" methods and properties for my classes that JUST derived or "friend" classes should know about and use them. You could declare the variable as the public class (NSString in my example) and "annotate" it with the "protected_protocol_name". In that case it would be both things for you.

Comment: @JZarzuela, I use that technique to make child 100% implement required methods, but in base class I want live that methods unimplemented and don't need compile warning about unimplemented methods. So I move that methods in protocol and make childs inherit  something like `Base<Base>`.